# how to make a div expandable depending on the length of its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have 6 different divs with the same height. Each div has a different content which means the length of their content won't necessarily be the same.

Now I want divs with a longer content to have a "read more" button which then expands the div to show it's full content. I got that part right.

However, how can I code it in a way that "read more" will only show up on the divs that have longer content which exceeds the height of the div?

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  var p = $('a').prev('p')
  var lineheight = parseInt(p.css('line-height'))
  if (parseInt(p.css('height')) == lineheight * 3) {
    p.css('height', 'auto');
    $(this).text('Less')
  } else {
    p.css('height', lineheight * 3 + 'px');
    $(this).text('More')
  }
});
```

```css
.inner-one h3,
.inner-two h3,
.inner-three h3,
.inner-four h3,
.inner-five h3,
.inner-six h3 {
  padding-left: 55px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inner-one p,
.inner-two p,
.inner-three p,
.inner-four p,
.inner-five p,
.inner-six p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 54px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one,
.two,
.three,
.four,
.five,
.six {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="one">
        <div class="inner-one">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
            adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a>More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="two">
        <div class="inner-two">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a>More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="three">
        <div class="inner-three">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a>More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="four">
        <div class="inner-four">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a>More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="five">
        <div class="inner-five">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a>More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="six">
        <div class="inner-six">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a>More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your snippet is missing a dependecy: $ (jQuery)

Comment: Well, when I input it in a codepen it works. Check this link: https://codepen.io/michelengelen/pen/WMZPoP ... oh sry, I misread something in your question ... I will update the pen

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this (comments in code).  I have also added common classes to make binding jquery events easier and gain css benefits such as easier to read code, less bloat (faster page load), etc

```js
$('.inner').each(function() {
  var $inner = $(this),
    pTag = $inner.find('p').eq(0).get(0), // get js object of first p
    isOverflowing = pTag.clientHeight < pTag.scrollHeight;  // see if it is overflowing

  if (isOverflowing) {
    $inner.append('<a href="#" class="more">More</a>');  // if it is append the a
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.more', function(e) {   // delegated event binding for more anchors
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this),
      $p = $link.prev('p');
      
      if ($link.text() == 'More') {
        $link.text('Less');                       // show text
        $p.data('height', $p.outerHeight());  
        $p.height($p.get(0).scrollHeight);
      } else {
        $link.text('More');                       // hide text
        $p.height($p.data('height'));
      }
})
```

```css
.inner-one h3,
.inner h3 {
  padding-left: 55px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inner p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 54px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.outer {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="outer one">
        <div class="inner inner-one">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="outer two">
        <div class="inner inner-two">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="outer three">
        <div class="inner inner-three">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="outer four">
        <div class="inner inner-four">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="outer five">
        <div class="inner inner-five">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="outer six">
        <div class="inner inner-six">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove static height of content from your CSS  and compare the height in jquery with fixed height if it is less, then do nothing and if it is greater, make it to fixed height and add MORE link

whenever you click on MORE link, the text should change to LESS, and height of content should be auto and whenever you click on LESS it should be fixed height with MORE link

Here is my code snippet

```js
$(".inner p").each(function(index) {
  var contentHeight = $(this).height();
  if (contentHeight > 50) {
    $(this).height(50);
    $(this).parent().find('.more').css('display', 'block');
  }
});

$('.more').click(function() {
  var ele = $(this).prev('p');

  if ($(this).text() == 'More') {
    ele.css('height', 'auto');
    $(this).text('Less');
  } else {
    ele.css('height', '50px');
    $(this).text('More');
  }
});
```

```css
.inner-one h3,
.inner-two h3,
.inner-three h3,
.inner-four h3,
.inner-five h3,
.inner-six h3 {
  padding-left: 55px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inner-one p,
.inner-two p,
.inner-three p,
.inner-four p,
.inner-five p,
.inner-six p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one,
.two,
.three,
.four,
.five,
.six {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="one">
        <div class="inner-one inner">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
            adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          </p>
          <a class="more">More</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="two">
        <div class="inner-two inner">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
            adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a class="more">More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="three">
        <div class="inner-three inner">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
            adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
            elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a class="more">More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="four">
        <div class="inner-four inner">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a class="more">More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="five">
        <div class="inner-five inner">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a class="more">More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="six">
        <div class="inner-six inner">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
            adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
            elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <a class="more">More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```